# How to implement Buttons inside Fragments

Tags: android-fragments

I find a nice layout on

http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/android-tabs-viewpager-swipe-able-tabs-ftw/

I add buttons to the xml fragments but I do not know how to implement the buttons, I mean, I do not know how to do for the buttons work.

Answer (score 0):

Each `Fragment` will load it's own layout, and the layout itself consists of a few buttons here and there - am I right?

If so, you can retrieve the `Button`s into variables. Consider the following:

```
Button myButtonOne = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.button_one);
myButtonOne.setOnClickListener(
    new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             handleButtonClick(view.getId());
        }
    }
);

private void handleButtonClick(final int resourceId) {
    switch( resourceId ) {
        case R.id.button_one:
            //Do something
            break;

        case R.id.button_two:
            //Do something
            break;

        case R.id.button_three:
            //Do something
            break;

        case R.id.button_four:
            //Do something
            break;

        case R.id.button_five:
            //Do something
            break;

        default:
            break;

    }

}
```

That way, you add your `OnClickListener`s, and then maintain them via the `handleButtonClick(int)` method (present in the class).

Comment: Yes, each fragment load its own xml layout with a few buttons but your response is only part of the job. According to http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: I add buttons to the xml fragments but I do not know how to implement the buttons, I mean, I do not know how to do for the buttons work.

The problem is that I need to create a callback interface inside the fragment and require that the host activity implement it and than the activity receives a callback through the interface:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Unfortunatelly, it is not clear how to do it with buttons.

In short, I have my buttons and I do not know how to make it work.